# How do you bundle up all sass files with webpack?

Tags: sass, webpack

I am using webpack to build  my es6 app. Unfortunately I cannot find out how to bundle all the SASS files into one single file to be imported from the main html page.

At the moment I compile sass like this in my JavaScript views:

```
require("./../scss/main.scss")
```

using the following loader:

```
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
}
```

But this is not what I want. I'd like to have an entry for the file `main.scss` and then have it dumped somewhere in the project, say the `public` folder where the `index.html` file lives too and from which it can be imported.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the extract-text-html plugin to do this.
In your webpack.config.js set this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),  


ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin"),
  HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
  path = require('path'),
  srcPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  sassLoaders = [
    "css-loader",
    "autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version",
    "sass-loader?indentedSyntax=sass&includePaths[]=" + path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
  ];
```

For the loader and plugin I recommend:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")},
      {test   : /\.woff|\.woff2|\.svg|.eot|\.ttf|\.png/, loader : 'url?prefix=font/&limit=10000&name=/assets/fonts/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("main.css"),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  ]
```

EDIT:
As you use the ExtractTextPlugin it'll place a css from the sass file all bundled together in the output folder.
You can place the name on the Plugin like: `new ExtractTextPlugin("main.css")`

Output

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public"),
  },
```

I recommend you check also the HtmlWebpackPlugin to inject the css and js in the html automatically and the CommonsChunkPlugin so you can build all your libs into a separated js and all your code in another, it really saves some time when debugging.

Comment: Where do I specify that the entry point is `main.scss` and that the output folder is `/public`?

Comment: Updated in the edit, if still have any doubt contat me, and maybe show your config file so I can make the changes in the file to make things easier.

Comment: I recommend you check my answer here too to clarify about comons pulgins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408898/why-is-my-webpack-bundle-js-and-vendor-bundle-js-so-incredibly-big/35413001#35413001