# Reactjs - HTML 5 adding color to <td> value

Tags: html, reactjs

How to add color to the html 5 `<td>` data?

for eg:

```
<td>{ this.props.item.status }</td>
```

Here I have to highlight status with some color.

Could anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS and Styling to a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545219/how-to-apply-css-and-styling-to-a-react-component)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/ this will be helpful

Comment: So you want to highlight the this.props.item.status?

Comment: yes.. want to highlight the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `style` tag in order to add style to your element:

```
    let tdStyle = {
        color: 'white',
    }
    <td style={tdStyle}>{ this.props.item.status }</td>
```

You can check official documentation [here](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html).