# React change a className's style using onClick from another tag

Tags: css, reactjs, classname

So I want to change the position of a div's className="myMenu" using onClick from a h1 tag element.To be more specific I have:

```
<div className="myMenu">
    <button onClick={()=> this.setState({ displayedComponent : Resume})}> Resume </button>
    <button onClick={()=> this.setState({ displayedComponent : Travel})}> Travel </button>
    <button onClick={()=> this.setState({ displayedComponent : Art})}> Art </button>
    <button onClick={()=> this.setState({ displayedComponent : Contact})}> Contact Me </button>
</div>
```

and I want to change myMenu's position using the onClick from

`<h1 onClick={()=> this.setState({ displayedComponent : Carousel})
*Here I would like to add something like document.getElementByClass('myMenu').style.position= 'absolute'* }> No mad Life </h1>`.

I want to change the myMenu.style.position just using the onClick event from h1 onClick="..."

I don't know how the syntax should be but I am pretty sure it doesn't work like normal js with document.getElementByClass('').style.position = 'absolute'.
Can anyone tell me how to manipulate this className's style?

Comment: Why are you using state to add more complexity? Why not just use Normal JavaScript?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `I want to change the position of a div's className using onClick from a .`

Comment: so I have a curent state of displayedComponent which is a Carousel. When I click on the <h1> it displays the Carousel and also is desplayed by default. After I have the myMenu in which I have another 4 components. When I click on each button it displays the component of that button. The thing is I want the myMenu to have absolut position when I display the Carousel. When I display other component I want that position to be gone. So I was thinking to change the the style of myMenu using the onClick event from my <h1> tag. How can I do that?

Comment: With Normal css. Don't add unnecessary complexity with state. Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545219/how-to-apply-css-and-styling-to-a-react-component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS and Styling to a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545219/how-to-apply-css-and-styling-to-a-react-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution, in the simplest terms, simply switch or append something to the classname on the  `myMenu` element, based on state.

```
<div className={`myMenu ${this.state.displayedComponent === Carousel ? 'modifier-class' : ''}`}>
```

And then add a css definition for the modifier class to position it absolutely