# Styling React Component with class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How can we define CSS class within react component, not in external style sheet? I know there is a concept call CSS module which solve the issue of global style sheet. Is there any other way to style component by defining classes with in component?

Comment: `className="theclass"`?

Comment: no i know i can apply class with className="theclass". but i am asking can i define theclass within component

Comment: As you can define styles as objects and pass them via the `style` property. But this is limited to a subset of css. A solution fully supporting all features of css is e.g. [styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/).

Comment: You can apply style directly,   eg.  `style={style}`  `const style={backgroundColor: green};`   But personally I think this is not ideal, I use less and then do something like `.myclass-button { /*style here*/ }`  and then of course do -> `<div className="myclass-button">...`

Comment: Depending on your webpack config, you can import your CSS file as `import 'myfile.css'`. If you use create-react-app, that comes out of the box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS and Styling to a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545219/how-to-apply-css-and-styling-to-a-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

[image]it's very simple, just run command "npm run eject" It moves create-react-app’s configuration files and dev/build/test scripts into you app directory.

now go to config folder and open 'webPackConfig.js' file and add the following code

```
          use: getStyleLoaders({
              ....
              ....
            modules:true,
            getLocalIdent:getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
            localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
          })
```

example:

```
import React from 'xyz';
import Logo from '../../Logo/Logo';

import classes from './Toolbar.css';
import NavigationItems from '../NavigationItems/NavigationItems';
import DrawerToggle from '../SideDrawer/DrawerToggle/DrawerToggle';

const toolbar = (props) => (
    <header className={classes.Toolbar}>
        <DrawerToggle clicked={props.DrawerToggleClicked}/>
        <div className={classes.Logo}>
            <Logo />
        </div>
        <nav className={classes.DesktopOnly}>
            <NavigationItems />
        </nav>
    </header>
);
export default toolbar;
```

try this and you can definitely solve your issue