# how to give margin to a functional component in react.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

here is my code that is returned by functional component:

```
return (

    <div className="card border-0 shadow " >
      <div className="card-header">Update a Book</div>
      <div className="card-body">
        <form onSubmit={(e) => onUpdateContact(e)}>
          <div className="form-group">
        
            <TextField
            id="outlined-helperText"
            label="Enter The Name"
            defaultValue={n}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            variant="outlined"
            
          />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
           
            <TextField
            id="outlined-helperText"
            label="Enter The Isbn"
            defaultValue={isb}
            onChange={(e) => setIsbn(e.target.value)}
            variant="outlined"
            
          />
          </div>
      
         
          <button className="btn btn-warning" type="submit">
            Update Book
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
```

i want to give left right margin to it ....how to do it ? when i type margin as attribute in `<div className="card border-0 shadow " >` ,it gives error

error:

```
<div className="card border-0 shadow " margin=20px >
```

Comment: style={{margin:'20px'}}

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: Duplicate: [How to apply CSS and Styling to a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545219/how-to-apply-css-and-styling-to-a-react-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need

```html
<div style={{margin: '0 20px'}}>
...Your content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`style`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) attribute:

```
<div className="card border-0 shadow" style={{margin: 20}} >
```

Or you can add the margin via CSS:

```
.card {
   margin: 20px;
}
```