# Using self made npm package in react. Failed to compile

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package, publish

I followed https://zellwk.com/blog/publish-to-npm/ to create my custom npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/demo-to-publish).
The folder structure of my custom package is as follows:

1. src -> index.js
2. node_modules
3. List item
4. Lable.js
5. package.json
6. webpack.config.js

Content of my package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "demo-to-publish",
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "description": "testing publishing to npm",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0"
  }
}
```

Contents of my index.js in src folder are as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Contents of my webpack.config.js are as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$|jsx/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

After publishing it to npm I installed it using `npm i demo-to-publish` in my new react cra app. I wrote the following code to use this package.

```
import Button from "demo-to-publish";
<Button/>
```

The error I am facing is in the screenshot attached below.

[image]

How to resolve this issue? 
Help me out as this is my first time publishing an npm package.

Comment: Dear Prakhar I think you are incorrectly using ``` { } ``` brackets with your return. only the render should be in brackets.

Comment: @izk Did you mean like this
```render() {
    <div>
      <button>Click me</button>
    </div>
  }
```

Comment: `render () { return <div> <button>Click me</button> </div>  };`

Comment: @izk Sorry, that didn't solve my issue. If it(Button.js) is used as a normal component, there is no error in the code. After publishing, it starts throwing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that `your code is not transpiled` and so it is not properly *recognised* by the browser and hence errors. By default, **create-react-app does not transpiles node_modules**.
You can find more here in a github issue  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3889

*The node module has no errors, just transpilation is the problem.*

---

## Fix

After going through the repo (https://github.com/prak-mtl/demo-to-publish), there are 2 possible fixes which can be done and are listed below. *Recommended solution will be 2nd one* but it requires you to do the build and then publish

### Solution 1

For this you need to do some changes in the both CRA and npm repo. You need to **add a configuration in the babel config** to transpile the specific node module. Since, CRA config is not changeable (unless you ejected the code), you need to add a additional configuration using `override` option.

#### - Do this step in the demo-to-publish repo

Inside the package.json of the npm package (i.e. https://github.com/prak-mtl/demo-to-publish/blob/master/package.json), you need to *change* the main path since we will be transpiling the code to new folder `lib`. Change it to `./lib/src/index.js` and republish the package.

#### - Do these steps in the CRA app

1. Create a file (`<any-name>.js`, *here* let's say `babel_override.js`)
2. Add the following code in babel_override.js:

```
module.exports = {
    overrides: [
        {
            test: ["./node_modules/demo-to-publish"],
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
        }
    ]
}
```

This will be used to transpile the code inside `demo-to-publish` in the node_modules folder in the CRA app

3. You should have `@babel/preset-react` installed. If not, then install it.
4. Delete and reinstall the demo-to-publish package in CRA app.
5. Before running the project, code needs to be transpiled, so run the following command in the terminal

```
NODE_ENV=development ./node_modules/.bin/babel ./node_modules/demo-to-publish -d ./node_modules/demo-to-publish/lib --config-file ./babel_override.js
```

- `NODE_ENV can be development, test or production
- `-d ./node_modules/demo-to-publish/lib` will published the transpiled code inside lib folder
- `--config-file` is the babel override config created in step 1. You should get success result of type: `Successfully compiled 3 files with Babel.`

  6. Run the project agian, it should now run fine

#### Solution 2 (*Recommended*)

This approach requires you to build the npm package. Since you already have the webpack, it shouldn't be a problem. The following steps needs to be done in `demo-to-publish` repo

1. Add library target as `commonjs2` in the output. The webpack config will become something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2' //This one the most important line, others things will remain same
  },
  module: {
    //Other code
  }
};
```

This will be used to output the build in `dist` folder.

2. In the package.json (https://github.com/prak-mtl/demo-to-publish/blob/master/package.json), we need to update the main attribute. Change its value from `./src/index.js` to `./dist/index.js`
3. Run npm run build in the repo. It should *create* a new folder `dist` containing one `index.js` file inside it
4. Publish the npm package now

Then, in the CRA app, install the package and run normally. It should work fine.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: I followed till step 3 but got stuck at step 4, here is the link to my repo *https://github.com/prak-mtl/demo-to-publish* please check.

Comment: My bad @PrakharMittal I should have mentioned the steps properly. I have updated the answer with proper steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. Now, it's working. Also, we have to write ```npx babel ./node_modules/.bin/babel ./node_modules/demo-to-publish -d ./node_modules/demo-to-publish/lib --config-file ./babel_override.js``` command to transpile.

Comment: `npx babel` is required only if you don't already have the babel node module. Otherwise, it should work fine without npx command.

Comment: My CSS and images are not getting transpiled/ available after using the above command. How to achieve that?

Comment: @PrakharMittal, You need to write different rules for CSS and images etc. I would advice you to read more on webpack and how to write different rules for various types of files. You can also look at [create-react-app webpack config](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js) to get a basic idea.

Answer (score -1):

If your class component does not have any state, it is recommended to use just functional component.

```
import React from "react"
export default const Button = () => (
  <div>
    <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I don't think the error is because of the component being a class-based component.

Comment: Are you using babel and webpack to bundle into package? This [link](https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce) might be useful for you since you're working on react component library.

Comment: I followed the same steps as were given in the document I read. I haven't used either of babel or webpack. I don't want to publish it by making a build but with the whole source code. Can you guide me on how to do this?