# CSS and Images files not coming after transpiling package with babel in new CRA

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, file-upload, babeljs

I am importing CSS as import './style.css'; and images in CSS with background URL property. What I want is to make a package, publish it to npm without building and then install it into a new CRA and use it there. [Using self made npm package in react. Failed to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077150/using-self-made-npm-package-in-react-failed-to-compile/60143350#60143350). From here I got to know that to use that installed package now I have to transpile it. But the issue is my js/jsx are getting transpiled from ES6 to ES5 but the images and CSS aren't coming into the new transpiled folder.

**DETAILS**
I made a package in Reactjs and was not able to use it after publishing the source, not by **making the build**.
Then I posted a question on it: [Using self made npm package in react. Failed to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077150/using-self-made-npm-package-in-react-failed-to-compile/60143350?noredirect=1#comment106912298_60143350).

Now I am able to use it by following the steps in the accepted answer i.e. by transpiling ./src using babel.

The issue on which I am still stuck is that I don't get my CSS and images in the new transpiled location i.e. ./lib/src. If I copy all the images and CSS folders in the respective places in ./lib/src. It works but I don't want to do it manually.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

WEBPACK.CONFIG.JS

```
module.exports = {
  overrides: [
    {
      test: ["./node_modules/<component_name>"],
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
      plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
    }
  ]
};
```

PACKAGE.json

```
{
  "name": "package-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "active-event-stack": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-webpack-loaders": "^0.9.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-draggable": "^2.2.6",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^5.10.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-resizable": "^1.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "wolfy87-eventemitter": "^5.2.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you create your react project through Create-React-app CLI or from scratch? I just don't understand your issue, are you importing those css files and images in your component correctly ? Have you tried to achieve the same thing with creating new project with CRA without changing the default configuration??

Comment: How are you loading your images and CSS? CSS modules? using import? using url() in CSS?

Comment: It seems you are using create-react-app (from seeing `react-scripts`). Your Webpack config will be ignored and it will use CRA's own Webpack config.

Comment: I have webpack of 4.41 version and babel of 7.8 version. I am importing CSS as import './style.css'; and images in CSS as background URL. What I want is to make a package, publish it to npm without building and then install it into a new CRA and use it there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077150/using-self-made-npm-package-in-react-failed-to-compile/60143350#60143350. From here I got to know that to use that installed package now I have to transpile it. But the issue is my js/jsx are getting transpiled from ES6 to ES5 but the images and CSS aren't coming into the new transpiled folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok if you want to publish a component library then there are plenty of tutorials available online, and if your specific issue is about not been able to publish your static resources such as `css` `images` and `scss` etc then you can just append a `cp` command  (linux & macos)  to your build script

```json
 "scripts": {

    "build": "babel src --out-dir lib --ignore src/__tests__/ && cp -R src/assets lib/",
  },
```

Notice this towards the end of the command `cp -R src/assets` this will manually copy your static assets to the desired location when your run `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) to load image files and [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) to load your css files.

Your webpack will then know how to deal with your files

If you have created your project with create-react-app. In that case, you just need to import your CSS file and image file to your components.

Comment: I am transpiling the files using babel not building it through webpack. So I don't believe your answer is applicable to my issue. Thanks, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this while importing css files :

```
import './style.css';
```

If you want to create this from scratch.

Inside your webpack.config.js , insert this (change the path according to your folder structure):

```
const path = require("path");

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "index.bundle.js"
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
  resolve: { modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"] },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    hot: true,
    port: 3000
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // this is so that we can compile any React,
        // ES6 and above into normal ES5 syntax
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        // we do not want anything from node_modules to be compiled
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
          "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
          "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
        loaders: ["file-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.html")
    })
  ]
};
```

and edit your .babelrc to contain just this:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

also your package.json should list these dev-dependencies:

@babel/core,@babel/node,@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties,@babel/preset-env,@babel/preset-react,babel-jest,babel-loader,css-loader,file-loader,html-webpack-plugin,path,style-loader,webpack,webpack-cli,webpack-dev-server

If this doesn't help please paste the link to your github repo. I will take a look.

Comment: You want me to make these changes in the new CRA app where I am using the published package or in the package itself.